# ¿ Como crear una pagina con determinados productos dentro de una tienda WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, diseño

Quiero crear una página en mi web en la que mostrar solo determinados productos de mi tienda online.
He creado una plantilla ( Productos Determinados ) tratando de añadir los productos que deseo mediante el `ID`, y luego, he creado un a pagina llamada MIS PRODUCTOS para la cual elegí la plantilla creada antes ( Productos Determinados).
En ella selecciono los productos por el `ID`, no se si habrá otra manera de hacerlo.
Pueden ver el código de la plantilla y me dirán que estoy haciendo mal, La pagina en cuestión muestra un producto por fila, y ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla.
Solo se muestra la imagen del producto ocupando todo el ancho de pantalla.

No hay forma de que puedan ver el ejemplo, ya que estoy en un proyecto Local
¿ Pueden ver los errores que estoy cometiendo en este código ?
Gracias

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Página de Productos Específicos
 * Descripción: Plantilla para mostrar productos específicos de diferentes categorías
 */

// Incluir el encabezado de WordPress
get_header();

// Obtener productos de diferentes categorías por su ID o slug
$product_ids = array(23, 45, 67); // ID de productos deseados
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__in' => $product_ids,
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Mostrar todos los productos
);

// Consultar los productos
$products_query = new WP_Query($args);

// Mostrar los productos
if ($products_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($products_query->have_posts()) :
        $products_query->the_post();
        global $product;
        ?>
        <div class="product-item">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo 'No se encontraron productos.';
endif;

// Incluir el pie de página de WordPress
get_footer();
```

Hice varias pruebas, pero siempre salen los productos desproporcionados.
Puedo mostrar alguna de las pruebas, pero hice muchas.
Algo no estoy teniendo encimera cuenta que no me permite crear el diseño como el de WooCommerce

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Salir si no se accede desde WordPress
}

/*
 * Template Name: Página de Productos Específicos
 * Descripción: Plantilla para mostrar productos específicos de diferentes categorías
 */

// Incluir el encabezado de WordPress
get_header();

// Obtener productos de diferentes categorías por su ID o slug
$product_ids = array(23, 45, 67); // ID de productos deseados

// Mostrar los productos con el bucle de WooCommerce
if ( ! empty( $product_ids ) ) {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce">';
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        $post_object = get_post( $product_id );
        setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    echo '</div>';
}

// Restaurar datos del bucle original
wp_reset_postdata();

// Incluir el pie de página de WordPress
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: prueba con   `do_shortcode("[products ids='$listpoductos' per_page='12' columns='3' paginate='true' limit='-1']")`

Comment: Cual es la finalidad? Digo que tienen de especial esos productos que no pueden aparecer con el resto? Porque no los pones en una categoría??

Comment: Puedes ser una buena opción, lo había pasado por alto @OCHOA. Los productos que quiero añadir en esta pagina, cada uno de ellos esta en otras categorías. Pero claro que podría hacerlo de ese modo.

Comment: Gracias @WAleman , pero no se donde podría añadir el array de productos

Comment: Hace unos días acá me pidieron una "Nueva Sección de Productos" (Productos en Oferta). Rápidamente cree la categoría y les dije, todo lo que quieran que esté en oferta lo meten en esa categoría y listo. Así que por un lado están los que crean los productos y por otro los de Marketing que ponen productos en Oferta xD (y yo que solo los veo pasar jajajsakdjasklj)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es increíble las vueltas que di destripando una plantilla de mil formas y lo tenia delante. El caso es que con otro tipo de productos si que lo hice así, mediante categoría... Gracias @OCHOA, si quieres añadir una respuesta, la aceptaré gustoso

Comment: Lo haré, ya que sino, la pregunta se pierde y luego el bot la revive por no tener respuesta aceptada. (cosa por la que estoy peleando en META en este momento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A veces, el concepto que nos dan es el que nos confunde, en mi caso eran **Productos en Oferta**. Como destacar productos en oferta a través de redes sociales por medio de un link?

Yo no me compliqué en lo absoluto, hice una **Categoría de Ofertas** y les dije a los de marketing que todo producto que quisieran ofertar lo metieran en esa categoría. Así, los creadores de productos crean los productos en X o Y categoría y sí los de marketing quieren ofertarlo, solo lo agregan a la Categoría de Ofertas y listo. Resuelto...